# WinForm C# programatically embedding an image in resx

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I am using VS 2005 for a windows application.

There have been code added in the UI form in past such that the form does not open in designer anymore.

I now have to add an icon in an System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.

Right now it simply adds images from the resource file in the InitilizedComponent() in the following way which I believe was originally generated by the designer.

this.MyimageListToolbar.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("MyimageListToolbar.ImageStream")));

In order to add my new icon I can simply say

Icon myIcon = new Icon(@"mypath/myicon.ico");
this.imgLstToolbar.Images.Add(myIcon);

but the problem then is that  I would have to include this ico file in the setup project so it gets copied when this sofware is installed. This is not desirable. All other images added on the imagelist tool bar are not copied when the application is installed.

Is there a way I can programatically add the icon or add the icon without using the designer and still have it included in the resource file so I dont have to copy the ico file in order to run the exe.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can add the icon to the "resource file" like so..

Right click on the folder "Resources" -> "Add" -> "Existing item..."

Comment: Yeah, that I have already done and I can see it the icon listed in the solution explorer but for some  reason the following line does not include it ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("MyimageListToolbar.ImageStream"))); and I have tried  icon as both "Content" and "Embedded resource"

Comment: What did you pass as argument to resources.GetObject()? I think it's a matter of getting the name right.

Comment: If you add myicon.ico to Resources, you should be able to access it like so: `global::NamespaceHere.Properties.Resources.myicon;`

Comment: The parameter I pass is a node <name > in the rsx file. The value in that node in the rsx file is all hex code which I believe represent all the other images added in the MyImageListToolBar. I believe for some reason the value there is not including the new icon I am trying to add.